# Memory usage increases with DrawText in Win32 C++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, memory, mfc

I have implemented a simple game using MFC. It contains images and formatted text. While testing, I found out that after the program runs for about 7 minutes without a problem, after that the images disappear and the text formatting resets. To identify the problem I rewrote a very basic version which only shows a formatted text. But the problem still continues, I have been googling for a day now but the problem is still the same. Here is my OnPaint method

```
    CPaintDC dc(this);

    CRect clientRect;
    GetClientRect(&clientRect);

    CDC bitmapDC;
    bitmapDC.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);

    CBitmap bitmap;
    bitmap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(&dc, clientRect.Width(), clientRect.Height());
    bitmapDC.SelectObject(&bitmap);

    CBrush backgroundBrush;
    backgroundBrush.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0xf8, 0xf8, 0xf8));
    bitmapDC.FillRect(&clientRect, &backgroundBrush);

    int SavedDc = bitmapDC.SaveDC();

    long nHeight = -MulDiv(20, GetDeviceCaps(bitmapDC, LOGPIXELSY), 72);
    HFONT myfont = CreateFont(nHeight, 0, 0, 0, FW_ULTRALIGHT, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_OUTLINE_PRECIS,
        CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, ANTIALIASED_QUALITY, VARIABLE_PITCH, TEXT("Arial"));

    bitmapDC.SelectObject(myfont);
    SetBkMode(bitmapDC, TRANSPARENT);

    bitmapDC.DrawText(L"This shouldn't happen", &clientRect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);

    dc.BitBlt(0, 0, clientRect.Width(), clientRect.Height(), &bitmapDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    bitmapDC.RestoreDC(SavedDc);
    backgroundBrush.DeleteObject();
    bitmap.DeleteObject();
    bitmapDC.DeleteDC();
```

I can see that the memory usage is increased gradually in visual studio. If I comment out the DrawText part ít does not increase any more. Am I doing something wrong? How can I keep the DrawText method from increasing memory usage? I have also tested with an image and it is the same problem. Should I somehow release or delete the DrawText? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're not deleting myfont.

Comment: @JonathanPotter you are right that stopped the increase. Just one follow up question, is it also enough to delete the CImage object if I want to draw an image? I just tested it and merely deleting the CImage does not stop the increase. Thank You so much for your help.

Comment: I don't see a CImage anywhere.

Comment: @JonathanPotter i had commented it out to test if the same thing happens only with text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disappearing images and fonts are a sign of leaked GDI resources, not the memory.

While it's pretty bad to leak memory, it's worse to leak resources, as they are pretty limited. Observe the `GDI Objects` column in the Task Manager for your game; when the counter hits 10,000 - you are done.

It is NOT enough to delete your MFC object holding the GDI resource, you need to first de-select them from DC (the currently selected object can not be released).

Comment: See [Debugging a GDI Resource Leak](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsui_team/2013/04/23/debugging-a-gdi-resource-leak/) for information on tools and strategies.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. One question though: How do I do the deselecting? From what I understand from your last sentence ReleaseDC will not do the trick, right?

Comment: @Revangelis - The `CDC::SelectObject()` returns a pointer to a previously selected object of that type; you simply need to save it and select it back into that DC. However, that may already be done in your code by `SaveDC()` / `RestoreDC()` calls.

Answer (score -1):

Just in case the objects selected into a DC are not able to delete, 
why don't you process strictly?

```
bitmapDC.SelectObject(&bitmap);
　↓
CBitmap* pbmold = bitmapDC.SelectObject(&bitmap);

(omission)

bitmapDC.SelectObject(pbmold); // addition
bitmap.DeleteObject();
bitmapDC.DeleteDC();
```

font is also the same as that...

Comment: Excuse me. you did that in savedc.